# Rename table with current month added

Tags: sql-server

We load the data to a table on daily basis, on month end we would like to rename it with current month added.

Tried with SP_Rename, but clueless how to add month name dynamically to the table

exec sp_rename old_table, new_table

Expecting to rename the table with month name added dynamically every month

Comment: I vote against doing this.  Just keep the table name the same, and remember that it contains the latest month's data.  If you want a month name, you can always query the table to get it.

Comment: You would have to do this using dynamic, as you must provide a string literal for the new table. But i agree with @TimBiegeleisen here. I have a very old database that uses this type of solution, and it's a pain in the ar.. to work with. Plus the fact that it's absolutely huge, due to the mass of data duplication. Ideally you should be keeping a row history and then you can get the information based on a specific date that way.

Comment: The dupe I suggested uses the full date, it should be easy to use only the month name or month number.

Comment: why not create a new table with the month-name, copy all data and then clear the original table